# Generator of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have a question about the generator of a stochastic process.

$T>0$: fix Let $b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded measurable function.
 Let $\left( (X_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}, \left(P_{x} \right)_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \right)$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-valued Brownian motion.

By Girsanov theorem, $\hat{X}_{t}:=X_{t}-\int_{0}^{t}b(X_{s})ds$ is a Brownian motion under $Q_{x}$. where 
\begin{align*}
\left. \frac{dQ_{x}}{dP_{x}} \right|_{\mathcal{F}_{t}}:=\exp \left(\int_{0}^{t}b(X_{s})dX_{s}-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t}b(X_{s})^{2}ds \right)
\end{align*}

**Question**

I want to determine the generator of $(X_{t},Q_{x})$. If $b$ is continuous, I can.

By Ito's formula, for $f \in C^{2}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{align*}
\frac{E_{x}^{Q}[f(X_{t})]-E_{x}^{Q}[f(X_{0})]}{t}
=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}E^{Q}_{x}\left[b(X_{s})f'(X_{s})+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_{s}) \right]ds
\end{align*}
By the continuity of $\displaystyle s \mapsto E^{Q}_{x}\left[b(X_{s})f'(X_{s})+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_{s}) \right] $, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{E_{x}^{Q}[f(X_{t})]-E_{x}^{Q}[f(X_{0})]}{t}
\to b(x)f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)
\end{align*}
I don't know when $b$ is not continuous. Perhaps we can't determine the generator? What should I do?

Thank you in advance.